# What authority did the US Army have in Egypt between 1945 and 1950?

Tags: united-states, military, egypt, post-war, decolonization

I am trying to research a brief period of time in Egypt immediately after Britain's withdrawal in 1945, specifically the presence and authority of the US military there (if any) before 1950.

Was there a physical presence, a military base? Did the US military have any authority, like for instance providing defense or security-related intelligence?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: For what it is worth, I just did a search, and I think this question may be more interesting than it initially appears. I couldn't find the answer.  Agree that the question would be better with prior research, but it is not trivial.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace  Perhaps, but some evidence of prior research would still be helpful.  For example, UK forces didn't withdraw in 1945. British forces [withdrew to the Suez Canal zone in 1947](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egypt%E2%80%93United_Kingdom_relations#Egyptian_independence_from_the_United_Kingdom), but didn't actually leave Egypt until the [Egyptian revolution of 1952](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_revolution_of_1952).

Comment: The question lacks any source that the US Army was in Egypt at all between 1945 and 1950.  **The U.S. Army's [Egypt–Libya Campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egypt%E2%80%93Libya_Campaign) ended on 12 February 1943, when the Allied forces finally succeeded in driving all Axis forces out of Libya.**